# How to set image in RecyclerView adapter from JSON data?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fresco

I am trying to load an image (retrieved from JSON data) into every item in my RecyclerView using the Fresco library. Only the placeholder image is being displayed for every item, not the images from the URLs that I would like.

I have `Fresco.initialize(mContext);` in my BookListAdapter constructor and `draweeView = view.findViewById(R.id.bookCoverDrawee` in my ViewHolder constructor. All of my other JSON data is being displayed in my RecyclerView CardView items.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Book book = bookList.get(i);
    viewHolder.singleListRowBinding.setBook(book);

    Log.d(TAG, "Image URL: " + book.getStrImageURL());

    if (book.getStrImageURL() != null) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(book.getStrImageURL());
        viewHolder.draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

The Log.d statement shows that the URL is correct, but the image isn't being set to the image from the URL.

In logcat, it does say that Fresco has already been initialised, but I don't know where else to put it (I've tried to initialise it where I initialise my adapter in another class and in my ViewHolder constructor). I've also tried using Picasso (since that doesn't require me to initialise it), but nothing gets displayed. Looking at [Fresco's RecyclerView adapter sample](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/drawee/DraweeRecyclerViewFragment.java), I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I don't mind using a different library if it works.

Please let me know if any more information is required. Thanks in advance!

**Update**: added XML as requested

```
 <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/bookCoverDrawee"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bookTitleTxt"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />
```

Full files:

[single_list_row.xml (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/LFjWKCaK)

[BookListAdapter.java (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/PSPbmUZ1)

Comment: show the code where you are actually calling fresco to set image from url.

Comment: Isn't that viewHolder.draweeView.setImageURI(uri);? If so, it's already in the question.

Comment: any other data is showing?

Comment: Is your other data from json visible in your recycler item ?

Comment: Yes, the other data from my JSON is visible in my recycler view items. I'm using DataBinding for that, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Book book = bookList.get(i);
        viewHolder.singleListRowBinding.setBook(book);

        Log.d(TAG, "Image URL: " + book.getStrImageURL());

        if (book.getStrImageURL() != null) {
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(book.getStrImageURL());
    ImageRequest request = ImageRequest.fromUri(imageUri);
    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder().setImageRequest(request).setOldController( viewHolder.draweeView.getController()).build();
   viewHolder.draweeView.setController(controller);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, this didn't work for me. The code runs, but I still only see the placeholder.

Comment: Are you loading image from file storage or remote url ?

Comment: URL (e.g. https://books.google.com/books/content?id=kotPYEqx7kMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api)

Comment: Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg"); 
try with this , if it works then there is an issue in URL.

Comment: That didn't work either. I think the URL is fine because I tested it somewhere else in my code (just setting one image, not for the recyclerview items) and it works fine.

Comment: Please add xml file in your question.

Comment: I've added the XML file that I use for every element in the RecyclerView. Let me know if you want me to add the RecyclerView XML file as well.